# Importing Unix timestamp into date time field

Tags: datetime, plugin-feedme

I have a Unix timestamp in my feed (1457685095000) and I am trying to map it to the date created entry field and I have another that I am trying to map to a time input field.

The created date is setting the date to a wildly incorrect value and the time field isn't getting set at all.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation for the [Date field](http://sgroup.com.au/plugins/feedme/importing-content/field-types#date-time), Feed Me uses [date_parse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php) to parse a provided date string into a proper date object. `date_parse` uses `strtotime` underneath, which seems to have issues with timestamps.

I just wanted to confirm your timestamp though, as it seems to not produce the correct date for me using:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1457685095000);

// Results in
48162-03-15 06:23:20
```

Comment: I believe that's a timestamp in milliseconds. Divide by 1,000 to get it in seconds as expected by that function.